# Why does the moon look bigger at the horizon?

Tags: sun, moon, vision, distance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the moon sometimes appear giant and a orange red color near the horizon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/25254/why-does-the-moon-sometimes-appear-giant-and-a-orange-red-color-near-the-horizon)

Why does the moon look bigger at horizon or skyline than at other times e.g. at moonrise and moonset. This effect can also be observed with the sun. And I think the difference between the distance at horizon and other time is not too much to be the cause of this effect. So what is the reason behind this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_illusion

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25254/2451 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20844/2451

Comment: Wow... it turns out romantic drama "Dear John" actually taught me something then... `No matter where you are in the world, the moon is never bigger than your thumb.`

Comment: Here is a [relevant site](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2010/10/why-the-moon-looks-bigger-on-the-horizon/) referenced in a now-deleted answer.