Why does the moon look bigger on the horizon, but buildings look smaller?
Read an answer saying atmospheric lensing causes the moon to look bigger but that's not true - according to lots of sites - it's a mystery in how the brain views things that's still imperfectly understood.  There's lots of pictures of the same sphere in back of a room or closer to you and, closer, you can see it's small, in back of the room it looks big.
So why doesn't the same thing happen with buildings? I mean if you're drawing/painting in perspective you'd draw a 'skyscraper' SMALLER on the horizon than if it was next to you, wouldn't you. So why doesn't that happen with the moon (Re. the moon, if I get howled at for 'dissing' atmospheric lensing, I can understand why people think that - I can also give lots of sites saying it's not so.)
I'm not really a physicist, I just love the subject!
Yours respectfully,
Chris.

The Moon is still over 363,300 km away, whether it is "on" the horizon or overhead. The horizon is only about 5km or less away for most people. It is really about how much angle something takes up of the 180° in front of you. A nearby building takes more angle than one on the horizon, but the Moon takes up about the same angle whether it is overhead or "on" the horizon>

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_illusion

Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43023/2451 and links therein.
